# Is this set convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have been trying to show that the following set is convex, with no luck. I am not even entirely convinced that it is in fact convex. A small hint would be greatly appreciated.
For $M>0:$
$$
\{g\in C([a,b])|\,\exists x\in [a,b]:\forall y\in [a,b]:\left|g(x)-g(y) \right|\leq M|x-y|\}
$$
To clarify: $x$ depends on $g$

Comment: What is $\;M\;$ ? Something that depends on each $\;g\;$ or not? I presume it is a positive constant, right?

Comment: Does $x$ depend on $g$?

Comment: I think there exists a continuous, nowhere Lipschitz function that might be used to construct a counter example but am currently unable to find a reference...

Answer (score 1):

The functions $f(x)=M(x-a)\cos(\omega x)$ and $g(x)=M(b-x)\cos(\omega x)$ are in the set, but their average $h(x)=M\frac{b-a}{2}\cos(\omega x)$ is not, provided $\omega$ is large enough.